# How to get uploaded image file size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

This is the problem. I am using Carrierwave to upload my images and now I am trying to get file size in KB for each version of my uploaded image. I've tried this but it gives me a wrong file size:

```
if @file
  img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
  size = img.to_blob.size
end
```

If I remove `to_blob` and try only with `img.size`, I receive error that `size` is not a defined method. Is there a way to get an image size in Carrierwave uploader while uploading file? Thanks all :)

Comment: try `img.file.size` [uploaded file size](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type)

Comment: @anonymousxxx, I get this error: `undefined method 'file' for #<Magick:: .....`

Answer (score -1):

The Carrierwave wiki has a recipe for how to implement this:
[https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type)

Comment: Thank you. This works for original image but how to access another image versions sizes?